# Program updating does not works properly

Tags: installation, auto-update

I have a program which has several versions. In the last version I have a problem: when I'm trying to update previous version to new one, the installer of new  version removes files from previous version, but don't installs new files. 
Just installing works fine, but updating process has this problem.

What can be the reason of this problem ?

Upade: I'll try to describe more detail
I have VS project where I have a project of program and an installer of this project. Till present all were working fine, but after my last big update ,the installer start work incorrectly.

And another question:
How I can debug installation process ?

Answer (score 0):

I dont know which program you have. Generally programs have problems because of multible versions, because programmers arrange this. For example ;

Lets consider Microsoft Framework. If you have 4.5 you cannot install 4.0, so that with similar idea you cannot update it.

Try to delete other versions and update them and install others. Or you can also stop services which you dont want to update.Then other one will be updated without any problem.